# Calling a function from another file to use in templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a function to create a percentage in this file

```
status.py

class Status:
    read_books = Books.objects.filter(read="True")
    all_books = Books.objects.all()

    def percentage(self):
        asdf = get_percentage(len(self.read_books),len(self.all_books))
        return asdf
```

I am trying to be able to use this function in my template to display this percentage by using something like this in my template

```
{{ status.percentage }}
```

Is this possible? would i have to put logic into my view in order to do this?

perhaps i could put this function in my view class and call it from there?

EDIT:

```
views.py

class BooksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'KPI/Books.html'
    read_books = Books.objects.filter(read="True")
    all_books = Books.objects.all()


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BooksView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_books'] = self.all_books
        context['read_books'] = self.read_books    
        return context
```

Comment: You pass a reference to a `Status` object in your `render(..)` call, with `'status'` as variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) you can just add your status object in the context. To do this, override the `get_context_data` method:

```
class myView(View):
    #...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        myStatus = Status()
        context['status'] = myStatus
        return context
```

Comment: Just one remark: `Status` is - as far as I can see - *not* a model class, it is more like a "utility class". +1 anyway :).

Comment: Yes it isnt a model class, and that answer works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. You only need to pass a `Status` object to the template engine (so for `render(..)` this is a context variable).

For example for a view, you can write this as:

```
from some_module.status import Status

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    status = Status()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', { 'status': status })
```

So now the template context contains a variable `status` that is just a `Status` object, and you can use it like other variables. If you write `{{ status.percentage }}` it will make a call to the `precentage` method.

In a class-based view, you thus "patch" the `get_context_data` method, like [@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54468251/67579) says:

```
from some_module.status import Status

class BooksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'KPI/Books.html'
    read_books = Books.objects.filter(read="True")
    all_books = Books.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BooksView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_books'] = self.all_books
        context['read_books'] = self.read_books
        context['status'] = Status()
        return context
```